# Microsoft SQL Query - Return last record from second table

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables which I am wanting to run a query on. The first table is `dbo.Incidents` which contacts the **primary key** `IncidentID.` The second table is `dbo.IncidentActions` which has the **primary key** `ActionID` and has a field `IncidentID` which links with the first table.

There are many actions with the same `IncidentID` and I am wanting to return 1 row only per `IncidentID` with the last `ActionID` for that `IncidentID`.

Thanks Andomar - nearly there I promise :)

```
select  *
from    (
        select  i.IncidentID
        ,       ia.ActionID
        ,      RIGHT('' + CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ia.ActionTime, CONVERT([varchar], GETDATE(), 14)) 
                         / 60 % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ' hr(s) ' + RIGHT('' + CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, ia.ActionTime, CONVERT([varchar], GETDATE(), 14)) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ' min(s)' AS LastActionTime

        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by i.IncidentID 
                    order by ia.ActionID desc) as rn
        from    dbo.Incident i
        join    dbo.IncidentAction ia
        on      i.IncidentID = ia.IncidentID
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

This is all working now I just want to set Where ia.ActionDate = GetDate() - can't seem to get that working

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the top `ActionID` per incident:

```
select  i.IncidentID
,       max(ia.ActionID) as MaxActionIdForIncident
from    Incidents i
join    IncidentActions ia
on      i.IncidentID = ia.IncidentID
group by
        i.IncidentID
```

If the `IncidentActions` table has a timestamp column you'd like to use to determine which row to return, you could use the `row_number()` window function:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  i.IncidentID
        ,       ia.ActionID
        ,       ia.ActionByUser -- Note: now you return any column
        ,       row_number() over (
                    partition by i.IncidentID 
                    order by ia.ActionTimestamp desc) as rn
        from    Incidents i
        join    IncidentActions ia
        on      i.IncidentID= ia.IncidentID
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Latest action per incident only
```

The subquery is required because you can't use window functions in the `where` clause.  For more examples, browse the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've updated the question at the bottom if you could help me with setting another Where condition.

Comment: Try `where cast(ActionDate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)`